# Can I update test plan by executing automated tests in build pipeline using Test assemblies

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, test-plan

I have a test plan in VSTS and I have associated automated test cases with the tests in VSTS. Now when I try to update the test plan by executing the automated tests in build pipeline "Select tests using" Test assemblies, the test plan is not getting updated

I tried to Select tests using Test Plan, then test plan is getting updated.

Can anyone help me in updating the test plan by selecting the tests using Test assemblies

Comment: Maybe it's just not supported. Check this [earlier post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/221741/executing-all-the-mstest-automated-tests-via-vsts.html).

Comment: What you encountered is expected behavior by design, if you do want the Test Assemblies to have the ability to update Test Plan, consider posting feature request in our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I update test plan by executing automated tests in build pipeline
>   using Test assemblies

Sorry but this's not currently supported. If we choose `Test Assembly` option, the test results won't be updated to Test Plan. This is **by design** of this task.

Just like the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/221741/executing-all-the-mstest-automated-tests-via-vsts.html) in comment above from **ReadyToLearn** states, if you want to update `Test Plan` automatically after test execution, you should use `Test Plan` instead of `Test Assemblies`. Hope my answer helps to resolve your puzzle :)